# Pythonic way to write cascading if statements

Tags: python, if-statement

Is there a more Pythonic way to write the following function?

```
def foo():
    flag = False
    if condition1:
        if condition2:
            flag = True
    return flag
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for the function to return exactly one of `True` or `False` then you can simplify like this:

```
def foo():
    return bool(condition1 and condition2)
```

This replicates *exactly* your code.

Comment: Hi @mhawke, why the need to cast?

Comment: See my comment in the answer that you just accepted. Your code _explicitly_ returns either `True` or `False`. The nested `if` can be simplified to `condition1 and condition2`, however, if `condition2` evaluates to a string for example, `condition1 and condition2` will evaluate to that string, not to `True`.Using `bool()` ensures that this code produces the same result as the code in your question.

Comment: @snowbound: whether you actually need to return exactly one of `True` or `False` is a separate issue. I would say that in general you needn't bother with using `bool()`, and instead rely on the "truthiness" of the expressions involved. But, in this case, your code was explicit, so my answer is too.

Comment: Thanks @mhawke. I didn't realise that either. **being explicit is better than implicit**. I've accepted your answer as the correct one :D

Comment: @snowbound: thanks. It isn't a case that being explicit is necessarily better, although it usually is, but that the code in this answer produces the same values as your code - which _is_ explicit in what it returns. Arguably it is better not to convert to a `bool`, and to rely on Python's [truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=truth#truth-value-testing)

Answer (score 5):

Here you go:

```
def foo():
    return bool(condition1 and condition2)
```

Comment: Subtly different to the OP's code, this will not return only one of `True` or `False`. For example, if `condition1 = 1` and `condition2 = 'two'`, then `(condition1 and condition2)` evaulates to `'two'`, not the boolean `True`.

Comment: Oops... I didn't think about that. Edited and upvoted your answer

Answer (score 4):

You could simplify it like below:

```
def foo:
   return condition1 and condition2
```

Note that the variable flag is not being used anywhere, and so it is perfectly fine to remove it in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Or even easier:

```
def foo(): 
    return condition1 and condition2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify it like this:

```
def foo:
    if condition1 and condition2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: I beg to differ. Generally you should avoid returning actual boolean values and just return whether it satisfies the condition or not.

Comment: @EddoHintoso: I beg to differ with you. The OP's code _explicitly_ returns one of `True` or `False` - as does this code. There can be conditions such as `True and 'truthy'` that would return `'truthy'`, not True nor False. Perhaps the conditions should be wrapped in a `bool()`.